# RobotFramework/RIDE can't pass sample test - "No keyword with name 'Run ${sakura}' found."

Tags: robotframework

**I'm trying sample test of RobotFramework/RIDE according to this article;**

> Desktop Application Automation With Robot Framework
>
> https://medium.com/@joonasvenlinen/desktop-application-automation-with-robot-framework-6dc39193a0c7

**Now, I'd set up ride and run it, and made first test code below;**

```
*** Settings ***

Documentation     sample
    Library           OperatingSystem
    Library           C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/AutoItLibrary/

*** Variables ***
    ${sakura}         C:\Sakura\sakura.exe

*** Test Cases ***

    first_test
        first_test_run

*** Keywords ***
    first_test_run
        log to console    Hello, world!  
        Run ${sakura}
```

**But when I run this test in ride, I got result report below;**

> command: pybot.bat --argumentfile c:\users\tie292~1\appdata\local\temp\RIDEujrsg3.d\argfile.txt --listener C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:57677:False C:\Users\tie292025\Desktop\first_test.robot
>   TestRunnerAgent: Running under CPython 2.7.13
>
> First Test :: sample
>
> first_test                                       Hello, world!| FAIL |
>
> No keyword with name 'Run ${sakura}' found.
>
> First Test :: sample                                   | FAIL |
>
> 1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
>
> 1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed

**My application environment is below;**

```
numpy==1.16.5
Pillow==6.2.1
Pygments==2.4.2
PyPubSub==3.3.0
pywin32==227
robotframework==3.1.2
robotframework-autoitlibrary==1.2.2
robotframework-ride==1.7.3.1
robotframeworklexer==1.1
six==1.13.0
wxPython==4.0.7.post2
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Please re-format the code in the question from `***Settings***` to `Run ${sakura}`. Current format does not look readable.

Comment: Most likely not related to RIDE, so the tag might be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test

```
 $ {sakura}    C:\\Sakura\\sakura.exe
```

or
     `Run     C:\\Sakura\\sakura.exe`

Comment: Or it could be an autoIt library problem.
Try reinstalling:

**1** `"C: Python37 Scripts pip" uninstall robotframework-autoitlibrary`  **2**
 `"C: Python37 Scripts pip" install robotframework-autoitlibrary`

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
I could test my first test case.

Answer (score 1):

Put two or more spaces between `Run` and `${sakura}`.

Now Robot tries to find a keyword called `Run ${sakura}` rather than a keyword `Run` with `${sakura}` value as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
I could go to the next step.